# Firestore query has somehow grouped the same users together

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this firestore code here and I have like to order it by createdAt desc. However when I ran it, it also group all the same users to be together. You can see the effect here at https://gamecrawl.com where the same users are put together. What did I do wrong here.

This happened only after I have added a query to get the nickname from the `users` collection.

```
var self = this;
let db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("posts")
  .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      self.channelId = doc.data().ytChannelId;
      self.userId = doc.data().uid;

      let getUser = db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", self.userId);
      getUser.get().then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(snapDoc) {
          self.nickname = snapDoc.data().username;
          console.log("nickname 73493");
          console.log(self.nickname);

          self.queryData.push({
            index: self.currentIndex,
            pid: doc.data().pid,
            title: doc.data().ytTitle,
            description: doc.data().ytDescription,
            imageurl: doc.data().ytImageUrl,
            ytid: doc.data().ytid,
            channelTitle: doc.data().ytChannelTitle,
            channelId: doc.data().ytChannelId,
            recommendation: doc.data().recommendation,
            userphoto: doc.data().photourl,
            votes: doc.data().noOfVotes,
            nickname: self.nickname
          });
          self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex + 1;
        });
      });

      // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just sort the queryData with a computed property and somehow it works.

```
computed: {
sortedQueryData: function() {
  this.queryData.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = new Date(a.createdAt),
      keyB = new Date(b.createdAt);
    // Compare the 2 dates
    if (keyA > keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA < keyB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  console.log(self.queryData);
  return this.queryData;
}
},
```

I am not sure why it is grouped together and I am still looking a better way to do this.  Somehow, this temporary solve the issue.